# How to achieve filling a path object on a canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, graphics

I have a problem filling a path drawn on a canvas. 
I read all those previous questions saying

```
Paint red = new Paint();
red.setColor(Color.RED);
red.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
```

should be the way it works. Then I drew my Path like

```
Path p = new Path();
p.moveTo(100,100); //point1
p.lineTo(200,200);
p.moveTo(200,200); //point2
p.lineTo(100,200);
p.moveTo(100,200); //point3
p.lineTo(100,100);
p.close();
```

Which should be a closed path in my opinion.
After canvas.drawPath(p, red); 
the triangle/path is drawn but not filled although style is FILL_AND_STROKE.
What am I getting wrong?

Comment: If you call `lineTo` you automatically move there as well. And the last `lineTo` is not necessary either, since close will go to where the path started. This should be one move, two lineTo, and one close _only_.

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no path to fill because your path consists of multiple lines, but no coherent polygon. See `moveTo` documentation, which reads:

> Set the beginning of the next contour to the point (x,y).

So by calling `moveTo` you are only drawing lines.

---

Only use `lineTo()`, which also "moves" to the target position. And you can skip the last `lineTo()` going to the point of origin, `close()` will do this automatically.

```
// create a triangle
Path p = new Path();
p.moveTo(100,100); //p1
p.lineTo(200,200); //p2
p.lineTo(100,200); //p3
p.close();
```